# How to use PageDown with <div contenteditable> instead of textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, contenteditable, pagedown

I would like to use [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) to make preview of Markdown text. But I use `<div contenteditable> </div>` instead of `<textarea> </textarea>`, so how I could do that?

I've tried code below, but that's seems don't working.

```
<div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
<div id="wmd-input" class="wmd-input" contenteditable></div>
<div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
```